# How wide should the framed opening be to accommodate double shed doors?

Tags: doors, shed, door-frame, barn

I'm building a shed/barn with a 6ft doorway for two 3ft doors.  If I assume the doors will be exactly 3 ft each, do I need to add extra space in the framed opening to allow them to swing easily, and if so how much?

Comment: It depends on the type and size of jambs and the type of astragal... you need to pick that stuff out before you frame the rough opening.

Comment: I'm building it all custom, so I can fit the jams however I want.

Comment: You are asking, specifically, how wide to frame the opening. **You need to plan your framing around how you will hinge the doors and what you will attach the hinges to (i.e. jambs)** Building it "custom" means nothing. You still need something to hinge the doors to and you frame to accommodate that.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it The hinges will not be standard indoor hinges that attach to a jamb and sit between the door and the framing. They will be strap hinges that will attach directly to the exterior of the barn and directly to the exterior of the door.

Comment: Excellent! You should edit your hinge plan into your question, it will make answers more helpful. Also, do you plan to utilize an *astragal* to cover the gap where the two doors meet in the middle? That will take some space too...

Comment: I had no plans to install an astragal (didn't even know what it meant). Assuming I do not, how wide should I frame the opening for two 3ft wide doors? There's no space needed for the hinges, and any dead bolt would be exterior as well.

Comment: A dead bolt on double barn door? You will need to have a secure anchor point on one of the doors probably both up and down.

Comment: @EdBeal By dead bolt I just mean a latch. Either in the middle between the doors to hold them closed, or vertically between the doors and the header. Either way, currently im still stuck on the sizing of the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll add a list of things to get your R.O.:

- The width of both door slabs together
- The width of both side jambs together
- 1" gap +/- for shimming the jambs plumb inside the framing (1/2" for each side)
- ~3/4" for slab gaps (1/4" each left, center, right)

The slab gaps may need to vary from 1/4" depending on your hinge and latch hardware. 3/16" (9/16" total) is more ideal, as it makes for better latch engagement, but requires fairly precise carpentry.

Of course, you can frame your opening and build the doors to fit it instead. Just work the same numbers.

Assuming standard outswing doors and 3/4" jambs, your 36" slabs would need:

```
1/2" + 3/4" + 1/4" + 36" + 1/4" + 36" + 1/4" + 3/4" + 1/2" = 75-1/4"
```

If, however, you don't use floating jambs, disregard the jamb thickness and the outer (1/2") gaps. You'd then simply have:

```
1/4" + 36" + 1/4" + 36" + 1/4" = 72-3/4"
```

An astragal doesn't usually add to r.o. in a simple shed scenario. It simply mounts to the face of one slab and laps over the opposing slab. There's really no need for it to be mounted to the edge of the slab. If you do want to use an astragal between the slabs for more stable latching, take that width into consideration.

Also, you mention that there's no space needed for your hinges. Even if you're using strap hinges you don't want the slabs tight to the jambs. That would be a recipe for binding and noise.

Comment: Excellent. Correct there are no jambs since the hinges are exterior, so the second calculation looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you purchase a set of prehung exterior shed doors that suit your design and budget. This is the simplest approach since the doors can be pre-drilled for the type of hardware (door handles, latches) that you want. The manufacturer will give you the dimensions for your rough opening which is going to be about 1 1/2 inches wider than your doors plus the jambs - although this dimension varies.

Answer (score 0):

Pick your door before framing. If you search [Home Depot's website](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Doors-Windows-Exterior-Doors-Front-Doors/72-x-80/Double-Door/N-5yc1vZar90Z1z0rbkoZ1z0sfqq) you will find both 74 in. x 81.625 in. for 36" wide doors and 72 in. x 80 in. for 6' wide rough opening.

Comment: Pre hung doors look to be $500+ which is more than I'm willing to spend on them. So I'll have to build these myself

Answer (score 0):

I have built lots of barn doors with 2x4 and plywood. The additional width comes down to the thickness of the doors and the type of hinges, drop on pin & strap style usually need close to 3” these are handy because the door can be removed when fully open providing the extra few inches clearance to get equipment in and out.
T style are also popular not removable but take up less room still the thickness of the door affects the needed opening , is the door going to be insulated ? A thicker door will be needed,

Comment: How does door thickness affect R.O.?

Comment: Where the hinges attach and with a 4” vs 2 “ you need more space for the swing and a wider RO.